# Horizontal alignment of text nodes of varying length in Tikz matrix like in Tex tabular

Tags: tikz-pgf, horizontal-alignment, matrices

In `tablular`, we use `{r|c|l}` to define alignment. Is there anything similar for `Tikz matrix`. For example, by using `matrix`, the following MWE produces matrix of nodes, which appear to be center aligned for each column.

However, I would like to have the nodes in the first column *right-aligned*, the middle column *center-aligned*, while the third column *left-aligned*. How would I achieve this? (also note, the nodes may have different styles)

```
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[align=center]
\matrix[matrix of nodes,row sep=0.5cm,column sep=2cm,
    nodes={rectangle, draw}]{
col1 & col2 & col3 \\
col111111111 & col2222222222 & col33333\\
col1111 & col22222 & col3333333333 \\
};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

yields this:

[image]

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Tikz matrices define the styles `column X` which allows to pass separate options (in this case, anchor) for different columns. For the record, the `row X` styles are the equivalent for rows, and you can combine both to refer to a specific cell.

```
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[align=center]
  \matrix[matrix of nodes,row sep=0.5cm,column sep=2cm,
    nodes={rectangle, draw},
    column 1/.style={anchor=base east},
    column 2/.style={anchor=base},
    column 3/.style={anchor=base west}
  ]{
    col1 & col2 & col3 \\
    col111111111 & col2222222222 & col33333\\
    col1111 & col22222 & col3333333333 \\
  };

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

More information is available in the [`pgfmanual`](http://ftp.math.purdue.edu/mirrors/ctan.org/graphics/pgf/base/doc/generic/pgf/pgfmanual.pdf) (section 17.3.3).

Comment: is there a convenient way to apply a column style to all columns?

Comment: @BrianFitzpatrick The `column` style applies the style to all cells of the column. So applying a style to all columns means applying the style to all cells of the matrix, so `every node` for example should do it.